# Create link pointing to particular article in web page

Tags: google-chrome, internet, browser, links

Assume I have web page http://www.albahari.com/threading/ with many text and articles in it. One of articles name is `Thread Pooling`. I would like to send my friend link to particular this article and not whole page from beginning. I would like construct link that scrolls down page in browser to particulate article `Thread Pooling` after clicking it. How to achieve that? How to find available direct links in web page?

Answer (score 6):

To go, as an example, to the article on "Thread Pooling", use the [link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling):

```
http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling
```

In general, look for an HTML element with the `id` attribute or, lacking that, the `name` attribute of the anchor tag at the top of the article that you want and use it, as above, after the `#` in the URL.

#### More detail

The html near the start of that particular article looks like:

```
<h1>
    <a name="_Thread_Pooling">Thread Pooling</a>
</h1>

<p>Whenever you start a thread, a few hundred microseconds
are spent organizing such things as a fresh private local variable stack. Each
thread also consumes (by default) around 1 MB of memory. The <i>thread pool</i> cuts these overheads by sharing and
recycling threads, allowing multithreading to be applied at a very granular
level without a performance penalty. This is useful when leveraging multicore
processors to execute computationally intensive code in parallel in
“divide-and-conquer” style.</p>
```

In the above, we can see:

```
<a name="_Thread_Pooling">
```

This tells us the string to use to identify the start of that article.  It is what we use in the URL that points to that article.

#### HTML5

As [grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity) points out, `name`, which worked in HTML4, is not supported by HTML5.  The `id` attribute should be used instead.  `id` can be used on [any HTML5 element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp), not just anchors.

Comment: Note that `<a name=...>` is old style (in fact no longer valid in HTML 5) since the same result can be achieved using the `id=` attribute on any tag (e.g. `<h1 id="_Thread_Pooling">`) and that's what most websites do nowadays.

Comment: @grawity Thanks for that!  I updated the answer to mention HTML5.

Comment: To clarify, `id=` was usable for this purpose even in HTML 4 and possibly earlier versions, it's not a new addition.